# Fetching Outlook email body

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to make a function that fetches the body of an email with a given search criteria. When I fetch items from the mailbox and try to get the body, it only writes part of the body. I want ALL text from the body instead. How can I do this? This is what I have so far:

```
        Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
        const string PR_HAS_ATTACH = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B";

        // Obtain Inbox
        Outlook.Folder folder = myApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder;


        Outlook.Table table = folder.GetTable(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlTableContents.olUserItems);

        // Remove default columns
        table.Columns.RemoveAll();

        // Add using built-in name
        table.Columns.Add("Subject");
        table.Columns.Add("ReceivedTime");
        table.Sort("ReceivedTime", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSortOrder.olDescending);

        // Add using namespace
        // Date received 
        table.Columns.Add("urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription");

        while (!table.EndOfTable)
        {
            Outlook.Row row = table.GetNextRow();
            if (row["Subject"].ToString().ToLower().Contains(subject.Text.ToLower()) && row["ReceivedTime"].ToString().Contains(cellCreationDate))
            {                    
                body.Text = row["urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Outlook.Table and then urn:shcemas:httpmail.textdescription to get the entire body. textdescription only returns the first 255 characters of the body as noted here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861580.aspx.

here is an alternative.

```
// change this in your code
body.Text = row["urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription"].ToString();

// To this
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
                             myApp.Session.GetItemFromID(row["EntryID"]);
body.Text = mailItem.Body;
```

Comment: This article says that you can still filter the table and then use the "EntryID" with GetItemFromID to get the entire body.

Comment: Thanks a million! I just needed to remember to add the column in the table for EntryID: table.Columns.Add("EntryID");